# Windows service not in the services list thought it is being installed successfully

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, windows-services

I have developed a Windows service using Visual Studio 2012 and I want to install it in my machine.

The code of the service:

```
public partial class OpenTableImporter : ServiceBase
    {
        public OpenTableImporter()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            EventLog.Log = "OpenTableImporterTableLog";
        }
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("The service was started successfully.", EventLogEntryType.Information);
            XMLReader xmlReader = new XMLReader();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("The service was stopped successfully.", EventLogEntryType.Information);
        }
```

This is the code of the program main:

```
public static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
         public static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new OpenTableImporter() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }
```

This is the log:

```
Installing assembly 'XXX\ImporterOpenTable.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole = 
   logfile = XXX\ImporterOpenTable.InstallLog
   assemblypath = XXX\ImporterOpenTable.exe
Installing service OpenTableImporter...
Service OpenTableImporter has been successfully installed.
Creating EventLog source OpenTableImporter in log OpenTableImporterTableLog...
Committing assembly 'XXX\ImporterOpenTable.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole = 
   logfile = XXX\ImporterOpenTable.InstallLog
   assemblypath = XXX\ImporterOpenTable.exe
```

I already:

- changed the `Startup Object` to my program.
- gave the `NETWORK SERVICE` read/write privileges to the Event Log.
- tried to make the `program.cs` class as public and then without public.
- ran Visual Studio as administrator and the cmd as administrator.
- added the installer for the service.

Comment: what makes you think it's not in the list of services? Did you refresh that list?

Comment: @KateGregory I am ashamed to say that, but I just found the problem, the service name is "importerOpenTable", but I was searching for "OpenTableImporter". I spent 7 hours, I am an idiot

Comment: happens to everyone. That's why I asked - name confusion is the number one cause of "missing" services

Comment: @KateGregory write an ansewr to accept it please

Comment: @KateGregory wait wait please, i didn't find the solution, it seems that there is no mistake in the service name :( help please

Comment: edit your question to include a screenshot of the services that covers the alphabetical range where your service should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually install the service, you have to register it with the Service Control manager. The simplest way to do this is with `SC.EXE`.

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192

Example:

```
SC.EXE create "MyService" binpath= "\"c:\program files\MyService\MyService.exe\" arg1 arg2" displayname= "My Service Name"
```

This creates a service, and tells the Service Control Manager that to start the service, it should call `"c:\program files\MyService\MyService.exe"` and pass the two parameters `arg1` and `arg2` on the commandline. For example, if it has `/debug` and `/service` options for those scenarios.

If your executable service doesn't require any special parameters to run the service you can omit those.

**Note:** If the path to the executable contains spaces then you need to quote it, using the backslash-double-quote, i.e. `\"` at the beginning and end of the path as I have in my example.

Comment: that is weird, in all the pages i hv read, `installutil` is the only command is needed, anyway I will start trying your solution and update you

Comment: sorry but I found the problem, which is there is no prblem, i installed `importerOpenTable` service while I was searching for `OpenTableImporter`. bty it is not me who downvote

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli, Installutil will also work it will do the same thing. However you don't mention anywhere that you have already tried Installutil!

Comment: yes i didn't mention that because i thought that is the only way to install the service, i am sorry

Comment: wait wait please, i didn't find the solution, it seems that there is no mistake in the service name :( help please

Comment: Marco, you may need to start DOS command window "As administrator" (right-click the "Command Prompt" and select option "Run as administrator") before you issue either InstallUtil or SC command in it.